# Run python script from PyCharm. Import in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import

It seems like Pycharm 1.5.3 makes some magic, or I missed something.

I have following file structure:

```
/sp
/sp/tools.py
/sp/test/main.py
```

Files contain following code

main.py:

```
__author__ = 'username'
import tools
import sys

def test1():
    print locals()
    print globals()
    print sys.path
    print test1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1()
```

tools.py:

```
class SettingsDictionary(dict):
    def __init__(self, seq, **kwargs):
        dict.__init__(self, seq, **kwargs)
```

When I run main.py this is written in console:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/Workspace/Python/sp/test/main.py
{}
{'test1': <function test1 at 0x0143D0B0>, '__warningregistry__': {("Not importing directory 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 1.5.3\\helpers\\tools': missing __init__.py", <type 'exceptions.ImportWarning'>, 2): True}, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'D:/Workspace/Python/sp/test/main.py', '__author__': 'p.grechishkin', 'sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, 'tools': <module 'tools' from 'D:\Workspace\Python\sp\tools.pyc'>, '__doc__': None}
['D:\\Workspace\\Python\\sp\\test', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-2.1.6-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_staticfiles-1.1.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_appconf-0.4-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\suds-0.4-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 1.5.3\\helpers', 'D:\\Workspace\\Python\\sp', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
<function test1 at 0x0143D0B0>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't understand why import function knows about this module 'tools': .
When I run this script from windows cmd - everything is okay. I get 'ImportError: No module named tools'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import work in the example you provided because your python path contains `D:\\Workspace\\Python\\sp` which is where your tools module is.

When you run a module from standard python interpreter, it only adds the path to current module in `sys.path`.

Comment: Is it some PyCharm function to add every directory to sys.path from 'tool.py' path? Looks like magic.

Comment: I don't know, I don't use that tool. You said it works in windows cmd after adding __init__.py. Is sys.path under pycharm still the same now ?

Comment: Yes, It is the same after adding __init__.py. Like it was before adding __init__.py.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `__init__.py` in the `/sp` directory.  Create a file with that name, and you should be able to import.

Comment: Yes, it works. But why python check parent directory for modules? I saw in doc that it searches only in built-in modules, and then in sys.path directories.

Comment: I feel that [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) can do a slightly better job of me explaining *why* at the moment.